# Why the List is not updated and why the var w is all the time null?

Tags: c#

In the button 8 click event i did:

```
 private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (buttonLockMode == true)
            {
                trackBar1.Enabled = true;
                button8.ForeColor = Color.Red;
                button8.Enabled = false;
                textBox1.Text = "Frame Number : " + trackBar1.Value;
                this.trackBar1.Select();
                textBox3.Enabled = true;
                textBox4.Enabled = true;
                wireObjectAnimation1 = new WireObjectAnimation(this, wireObject1);
                int currentFrameIndexRight = trackBar1.Value;
                wireObjectCoordinates1 = new WireObjectCoordinates() { FrameNumber = currentFrameIndexRight };
                WireObjectCoordinatesCloneFrame();

                List<WireObjectCoordinates>  temp = wireObjectAnimation1.CoordinatesList;
                temp.Add(wireObjectCoordinates1);
                //wireObjectAnimation1.CoordinatesList.Add(wireObjectCoordinates1);

                //WireObjectCoordinatesCloneFrame();

            }
            else
            {
                button8.ForeColor = Color.Black;
            }
        }
```

Phoog i used the same idea of temp List.
And in the wireObjectanimation i did:

```
private List<WireObjectCoordinates> _coordinateslist = new List<WireObjectCoordinates>();
        public List<WireObjectCoordinates> CoordinatesList
        {
            get { return _coordinateslist; } 
        }
```

And still when i put a breakpoint on the get line the _coordinateslist and CoordinatesList both empty.

Comment: That is a LOT of code to ask someone to review.  Can you distill this down to the core issue?

Comment: your question is almost unreadable. maybe you should edit it abit, to make it more clear

Comment: can you give a SSCCE, Short, Self-Contained Correct Example?

Comment: Sorry.  I really did want to help, but I spent a lot of time trying to understand the first four sections of code, then I realized that I was only a third of the way through the question and I hadn't even gotten to the question mark yet.  If you distill this down to a much much shorter question, I would be happy to read it and help in any way I can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`First` throws if there's no element that satisfies the predicate.  It follows that there's most likely no item in the `_coordinatesList` whose `FrameNumber` is equal to `currentFrameIndex`.

Try this:  Change `catch` to `catch (Exception e)` and when execution enteres the catch block, use the debugger to examine the exception.  Or, set your debugger to break on handled exceptions, which will also give you the opportunity to examine the exception.

Once you've determined whether the hypothesis is true, that is, that there's no element in the sequence that satisfies the predicate, you can proceed to the next step, which is to determine *why* there's no element that satisfies the predicate: either your expectation is wrong, or the code that is supposed to satisfy the expectation is wrong.

This is a great example of why you should never use `catch { }` in your code.

It would also be helpful if you stick to code conventions.  An identifier like `_coordinatesList` would typically be a private field; `WireObjectCoordinatesList` would typically be a public property.  You have it backwards, which is confusing.

Regarding the breakpoint in the list getter:

> I put a breakpoint on the get and it stop there when i click on button8 But now the List _coordinatesList is empty. If i put the breakpoint on Form1 button8 click event i see the List is containing the point coordinates but when im in wireObjectanimation class the List is empty.

Consider this code:

```
private List<string> _words = new List<string>();
public List<string> Words { get { return _words; } }
```

And this calling code:

```
void AddAWord(string word)
{
    this.Words.Add(word);
}
```

That calling code is equivalent to this:

```
void AddAWord(string word)
{
    List<string> temp = this.Words;
    temp.Add(word);
}
```

In other words, the property getter first returns the list to `AddAWord`, and then `AddAWord` calls `Add` on the list.  Thet's most likely the reason why the list doesn't yet contain anything when you put the breakpoint in the property getter.

EDIT

I did not mean to suggest that adding a temp variable would solve your problem.  Rather, the temp variable is intended to clarify why the problem is occurring.  Adding the temp variable does not change the meaning of the code.  In fact, the C# compiler may well create the temp variable implicitly.

Perhaps I misunderstood what you've done and what you're expecting, but to me it looks like your expectations are incorrect.  In other words, you've put your breakpoint on the wrong line.

Consider:

```
1  private List<WireObjectCoordinates> _coordinateslist = new List<WireObjectCoordinates>();  
2  public List<WireObjectCoordinates> CoordinatesList  
3  {  
4      get { return _coordinateslist; } // <<< your breakpoint here
5  }  
6
7  private void button8_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)   
8  {   
9      if (buttonLockMode == true)   
10     {
11         // ...
12         List<WireObjectCoordinates>  temp = wireObjectAnimation1.CoordinatesList; // <<< my breakpoint here
13         temp.Add(wireObjectCoordinates1);
14     }   
15     else   
16     {   
17         // ...
```

Now step through the code.  You have a breakpoint on line 4.  I am adding a breakpoint at line 12.  We hit line 12 first.  Hit F11.  Execution moves to line 4, which is your breakpoint.  Note that the list is empty.  Of course it is empty, because we haven't reached line 13 yet.

Hit F11 a couple of times to step through the property getter.  The execution point returns to line 12.  The `temp` variable is still null.  Hit F11 once more to assign the property value to the `temp` variable.  Execution moves to line 13.

Hit F11 once more.  This calls the `Add` method.  Now the list contains one element.

My point is that this sequence of instructions is the same regardless of whether there's a temp variable or not.  Consider a single-line expression, like this:

```
wireObjectAnimation1.CoordinatesList.Add(wireObjectCoordinates1);
```

The following steps happen, in this order:

- Determine the object referred to by `wireObjectAnimation1`
- Call the `CoordinatesList` getter on that object
- Call the `Add` method on the the object returned by the `CoordinatesList` getter in the previous step

Your breakpoint is in the second step; `Add` is called in the third step; the list is therefore empty when you hit the breakpoint.

Comment: Phoog i will edit my question and make it shorter and show you what i did and changed still not working.

Comment: @user1477444 Sorry for the slow response; I've been busy this week.  I've edited my answer to address your edited question.